# How to use Pageable In Kendo TreeList?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treelist

How to use Pageable In Kendo TreeList ??
Please Help Me to Add Pageable  to Kendo TreeList ??

How can we arrange KENDO TREELIST?
Is it possible to paging at all?

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeList<Auditing.Models.DomainModels.EF.test>()
    .Name("AccessTreeList")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {      


    })
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
    .Events(events =>
    {

        events.ColumnMenuInit("RemoveHide");
        events.DataBound("mergeColumn10");
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("FillGrid_Tree", "Balance"))
        .Aggregates(aggregates =>
        {
            aggregates.Add(ss => ss.CreditorAmountInDuringPeriod).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(ss => ss.CreditorAmountInBeginningPeriod).Sum();

        })
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Model(m =>
        {
            m.Id(f => f.Id);
            m.ParentId(f => f.ParentId);
            m.Expanded(false);
            m.Field(p => p.TurningId_P);
            m.Field(p => p.Name);
            m.Field(p => p.Name_turning);


        })
).ColumnMenu())
```

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo TreeList doesn't support pagination out of the box but it can be done. You can see a solution in [this post](https://www.telerik.com/forums/does-treelist-support-pagination) in Telerik's forums.

Comment: Why? If you elaborate perhaps a solution can be found.